# Passenger memory stats decomposing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

I've been looking for info on fusion passenger's memory stats (passenger-memory-stats) and haven't quite found what I'm looking for. For example below is stats for my latest app.

```
---- Passenger processes -----
PID   VMSize    Private  Name
------------------------------
4238  22.9 MB   0.3 MB   PassengerWatchdog
4241  31.7 MB   0.4 MB   PassengerHelperAgent
4243  42.5 MB   6.7 MB   Passenger spawn server
4246  72.9 MB   0.7 MB   PassengerLoggingAgent
4403  273.3 MB  31.4 MB  Passenger ApplicationSpawner: /var/www/TheApp
4556  281.0 MB  34.9 MB  Rack: /var/www/TheApp
### Processes: 6
### Total private dirty RSS: 74.42 MB
```

What I'd like to grasp in more detail is

1. What is the relation between VMSize and Private and what to look for in those?
2. As of my understanding now, the private dirty RSS is the real memory usage and if so, do I have to care for the virtual memory sizes at all?

Comment: As for 2.: yes you need to care about the virtual memory size. My understanding is, that the total of all VMSize needs to be less than your physical + swap size.